# Using JQuery Multisortable plus filtering a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-multisortable

So, here is the problem...

I have two lists. I want the user to be able to drag from one list on the left to build a new list on the right, but also want to give them the ability to filter the left list.  The left list could be quite long so I also want them to be able to multi-select and drag.

For multi-select I am using [jQuery multisortable](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Multi-Sortable-Plugin-jQuery-UI.html)

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nickgates100/25x3w9eg/84/) to show what I am trying to achieve.

The ultimate goal is to build a comma delimited string for the built list. If you filter the list on "a", multiselect the results and you will see that all list items are dragged to the right list - even the ones in between the filtered items that are hidden by the filter - How do I get around this?

Any help appreciated!

The below example is using Bootstrap 4

EDIT: Looking at the DOM I can see that JQuery filter adds a class "multiselectable-shift" when the SHIFT key is used to multi-select items, so tried adding the option...

items: '> li:not("multiselectable-shift")'

...to the sortable's, still no joy.  Using the control key or meta kay is fine, it's just the shift key that is the issue.

```js
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('ul.connectedSortable').multisortable({
      selectedClass: 'highlight'
    });
    $('ul#sortable1').sortable({
      connectWith: 'ul#sortable2',
      update: function() {
        callListIds = "";
        $("ul#sortable2 li").each(function() {
          callListIds += $(this).attr("id") + ",";
        })
        callListIds = callListIds.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
        $("#listIdResult").html(callListIds);
      }
    });
    $('ul#sortable2').sortable({
      connectWith: 'ul#sortable1',
      update: function() {
        callListIds = "";
        $("ul#sortable2 li").each(function() {
          callListIds += $(this).attr("id") + ",";
        })
        callListIds = callListIds.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
        $("#listIdResult").html(callListIds);
      }
    });
  });
// Search field
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#sortable1 li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
}); </script>
```

```css
.highlight { 
  background-color: #AABFF3;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script   src="https://rawgithub.com/shvetsgroup/jquery.multisortable/master/src/jquery.multisortable.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    .highlight {  background-color: #AABFF3; }
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <input type="hidden" name="callListIds" id="callListIds" value="">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center w-90 mx-auto d-block pt-5">
      <div class="container w-40 float-left">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search...">
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable list-group" style="min-height:100%">
          <li id="ls1" class="list-group-item w-100 p-1">ABC</li>
          <li id="ls2" class="list-group-item w-100 p-1">DEF</li>
          <li id="ls3" class="list-group-item w-100 p-1">AGH</li>
          <li id="ls4" class="list-group-item w-100 p-1">HIJ</li>
          <li id="ls5" class="list-group-item w-100 p-1">KLM</li>
          <li id="ls6" class="list-group-item w-100 p-1">AOP</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="container w-40 float-right border ml-1">
        <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable list-group" style="min-height:100%">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="p-2 text-center">Resulting comma delimited String:
      <span id="listIdResult"></span></p>
    </body
```

Comment: When I test your fiddle, by running a filter and then selecting multiple items and dragging them over, I just get the items I selected. Not able to replicate it as you described.

Comment: I was able to replicate it with very specific steps. 1) Click and item to select it 2) Filter for "a" 3) Shift-Click an item 4) Drag items over. I got 5 items instead of 2. If I filter first and then select, it works as expected.

Comment: So the issue is that when you Shift-Click to Select a group, it is selecting all items not just Visible items. This is a limitation to multiselect and you will need to see if you cna use `:visible` selector.

Comment: Thank you guys for comments.  Yes, issue is simply with the SHIFT key. If you filter on "a" it filters to three items. When you click on the first item, then the third item and drag, all items including those hidden by the filter get dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there is a logic issue in the code [https://github.com/shvetsgroup/jquery.multisortable/blob/master/src/jquery.multisortable.js 44-56]:

```
if (e.shiftKey) {
  var last_shift_range = parent.find('.multiselectable-shift');

  last_shift_range.removeClass(options.selectedClass).removeClass('multiselectable-shift');

  var shift_range;
  if (prevIndex < myIndex) {
    shift_range = item.prevUntil('.multiselectable-previous').add(prev).add(item);
  }
  else if (prevIndex > myIndex) {
    shift_range = item.nextUntil('.multiselectable-previous').add(prev).add(item);
  }
  shift_range.addClass(options.selectedClass).addClass('multiselectable-shift');
}
```

Basically, it's ignoring `items` option when creating the range. So when you configure like so:

```
$(el).multiselect({
  items: "li:visible"
});
```

A Shift Click event will create a Range and include all the list items, if they are visible or not. I've tried a couple work around and have refined the Fiddle to this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/sjg5u1ty/56/

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.fn.filterList = function(t) {
    console.log("Filter For:", t);
    $("> li", this).each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).toggle($(el).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(t.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    });
    $(this).multisortable("option", "items", "> li:visible").multisortable("refresh");
  }

  function listToString(el) {
    return $(el).sortable("toArray").toString();
  }

  $('ul.sortable').multisortable({
    selectedClass: 'highlight'
  }).sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    update: function(e, ui) {
      $("#listIdResult").html(listToString(this));
    }
  });

  $("#search").on("input", function(e) {
    $("#sort-1").filterList($(this).val());
  });
});
```

In theory, this should work yet it does not. When the list is filtered, it should update the Options and refresh what can be selected. I'm not sure this can be "fixed" with the Plugin at preset and since it's not gotten an update for 7 years, I doubt there is a fix coming.

There may be a better answer, yet I do not have one right now. Will investigate and update this answer if I come across anything.

Comment: Thanks Twisty! I'll leave it a few days but I think this is likely the correct answer.  The issue does seem to be the plugin code and for now I have just set it to RETURN on if(e.shiftKey) Your code is so much better than mine though!  Really, really appreciate the time you have taken!